# Duplicate REST API Calls inside Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have an angular controller. At the beginning of the controller, I want to call a REST API to initialize one object.

I am using the Angular $Resource to do it.

```html
function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("common.services")
    .factory("hostAgentResource",
            ["$resource",
             hostAgentResource]);

function hostAgentResource($resource) {
    
    var brokerSvcUrl = "http://localhost:13898";
    return $resource(brokerSvcUrl + "/api/HostAgent")
    
}

}());

hostAgentResource.query({ agentNicHash: vm.product.hostAgentNicHash }, function (data) {
            vm.productDetail = data[0];
        });
```

And here is my controller signature

```html
  angular
        .module("productManagement")
        .controller("ProductEditCtrl",
        ["productResource",
            "userResource",
            "hostAgentResource",
            "shareDataService",
           "$state",
            "$http",
            ProductEditCtrl]);


    function ProductEditCtrl(productResource, userResource, hostAgentResource,shareDataService, $state, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        if ($state.params["clientId"] >= 0) {
            vm.product = shareDataService.getValue("currentProduct");
            vm.title = "Edit:" + vm.product.hostName;
        } else
        {
            vm.product = {};
            vm.product.clientId = -1;
            vm.title = "New Desktop";
        }
        
        hostAgentResource.query({ agentNicHash: vm.product.hostAgentNicHash }, function (data) {
            vm.productDetail = data[0];
        });
```

My question is that somehow, the hostAgentResource.query was called 4 times when I load the controller. I only expect an onetime call to initialize the vm.productDetail.

Is it because I have multiple external dependency object being injected in?

Comment: Not enough information. Couple of small code snippets and no showing us usage or anything isn't too helpful.

Comment: why you have $resource method in your `factory`

Comment: @PankajParkar I want to encapsulate the REST API logic into a public service as there are multiple module will use the same REST data source.

Comment: @Phill my question is quite generic, when the controller get loaded, somehow the hostAgentResource.query was called multiple times. (more precisely, 4 times). I am not sure what cause the multiple call, thus I suspect it is the external dependency object I injected in.